# To build a 'very snappy' Rails app - JS MVC or WebSockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, websocket, ember.js

I want to build an app that needs to be pretty snappy, on the front-end, and do all sorts of fluid UI stuff.

Am I better off using something like Backbone, Node or Ember - or just using a WebSockets gem like [EM-Websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) and PJax?

Why might I want to use one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Would love to know why the 'close' votes.

Comment: you could probably improve your question by making it more like "given these requirements, which of these two frameworks is best suited?"

Comment: @Dean, the issue is that it's not a choice between two frameworks. Backbone, Node, Ember are all on one side of the debate (i.e. JS MVC frameworks) and EM-WebSockets is a gem that implements HTTP WebSockets in Ruby. So it's not as simple as that. If you have a suggestion, for how I might avoid the mods wrath - please do share.

Comment: The issues are twofold. First, it's a discussion question because it doesn't offer a series of requirements and constraints sufficient enough for someone to give you an answer that isn't going to boil down to opinion or preference. Second, if you gave us enough detail to make that decision the question would then be so long and detailed as to be impossible to read and then answer (it would also be way too specific to your case). Discussion questions really aren't designed to be addressed on StackOverflow, and should be taken up with the relevant communities and discussion forums.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how you can avoid the mods wrath with this one... try making it more specific somehow... perhaps by giving an example use case that can be tested against. The problem here, and as you used the term yourself, is that your current question is debatable.

Comment: @normalocity Where would I be able to get an objective answer to this type of question though? Naturally, any community forum for a particular technology is going to have a strong bias towards that particular technology. I know this question doesn't have a clear cut answer - but does that make it not valuable to other developers who have choices to make about this particular scenario and want to make an informed decision?

Comment: Well, I don't think you can get an objective answer, which is kind of my point. The opinion element to it makes this more of a discussion question. It's not that this is a bad question to ask on the internet, it's that StackOverflow isn't designed for discussion questions and generally disallows such questions. Also, it's generally not the moderators that are closing things - anyone with enough reputation (3,000 rep minimum) in the community can vote to close questions.